# What is $\frac{(an)!}{n!}$?

Tags: factorial

How can $\frac{(an)!}{n!}$ be expressed in terms of $a!$, $n!$, $a$, $n$ (and maybe Pochhammers)?

Comment: What makes you think that it can?

Comment: It can't. Let $a=2$, $n=3$, then your number has a factor $5$, which none of $a!$, $n!$, $a$, or $n$ have.

Comment: Can't we use Pochhammer symbols?

Comment: If all you want to do is avoid $(an)!$, you have $[(a-1)n]!{an\choose n}$ or (with Pochhammer symbols) $\frac{(an)_{an}}{n!}$.

Comment: @vadim123 make that an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't insist on being exact, you can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).  $$\frac{(an)!}{n!}\approx \frac {(an)^{an}e^n}{n^ne^{an}}\sqrt{a}=a^{an}n^{an-1}e^{-(an-1)}\sqrt a$$ which will be very close-within about a factor of $1+\frac 1{12n}$

Comment: So the accuracy increases with an increase in $n$?

Comment: Yes, it does.  And for $n=10$ you are already within $1\%$  This is very useful for large factorials.

Comment: Nice, thanks - but it unfortunately doesn't meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

By OP's request, my above comment was that since $m!=(m)_m$, we may write the desired expression as $$\frac{(an)_{an}}{a!}$$

Note: this solution is not the one @lhf commented on, below.

Comment: This argument is only correct if you assume that "in terms of" means "multiplicatively". In principle, there might be an expression involving addition and then other primes might show up.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>m$,
$$
\frac{n!}{m!} = P(n,n-m) = \text{the number of permutations of $n-m$ in a set of $n$}.
$$
This is one context in which it doesn't make sense to define "permutation" as a bijection from a set to itself, but rather one should define it as an ordered list of length $n-m$ of members of a set of size $n$.